# Why am I getting an indexing error even though I'm not trying to index anywhere?

Tags: matlab, indexing, rms

I execute a single command and I get:

```
>> rms = rms(distances(1:50,1))
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

`distances` is just a vector of non-negative doubles.

Comment: Try changing the variable name you are saving to. You might have to delete it in the workspace first.

Comment: The point is: is `distances` a vector of **positive integers** and does **NOT** contain zeroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling this more than one time, you saved the result of `rms(distances(1:50,1))`, which is a scalar double, to the variable `rms`. So `rms` is not anymore a function, but a scalar, and with every subsequent call you attempt to index into `rms` with your non-negative doubles. It is as if you did the following:

```
x = 1.1; 
x(5.4)
```

In general, never save results to function names. Instead, do the following:

```
clear rms
distancesRMS = rms(distances(1:50,1));
```